# How to call a the python code when a new message is delivered from telethon API

Tags: telethon

How can I call some Python code when a new message is delivered from the Telethon API? I need to run the code all the day so that I can do my processing from Python code.

1. How to use this? `@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel, incoming=True))`
2. Do I need run the scheduler to check this?

I am using `history = client(GetHistoryRequest)` method.

Answer (score 1):

[First Steps - Updates](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html) in the documentation greets you with the following code:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Note you can "call" any Python code inside `my_event_handler`. It also shows how `@client.on()` is meant to be used. Note there is no need for a scheduler.

---

> I am using history = client(GetHistoryRequest) method.

As a side note this is raw API which is discouraged if a friendly alternative, like [`client.get_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages), exists.